# Mount samba shared directory as user home folder on the guest virtual machine

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, virtualization, home-directory

I want to run several Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machines based on `libvirt` that share the same home folder for the user.
On the host I created the following samba shared folder:

```
lsblk
sdd                          8:48   0   1.9T  0 disk  
└─luks-46538...
                        253:2    0   1.9T  0 crypt 
└─data-ubuntu--gpu--home 253:10   0  1000G  0 lvm   /mnt/shared_home
```

on the host I created the group `editors` to make them access shared folders following this guide [How to create a Samba share on Ubuntu Server 20.04](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-samba-share-on-ubuntu-server-20-04/).

From /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[AABOR-HOME]
    comment = aabor-samba-home
    path = /mnt/shared_home/aabor
    valid users = @editors
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
[MEDIA]
    comment = aabor-samba-media
    path = /mnt/media
    valid users = @editors
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
```

then on the VM guest I add to /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.0.5/aabor-home                  /home/aabor     cifs    rw,relatime,cache=strict,username=aabor,password=<pwd>,domain=WORKGROUP,gid=1000,uid=1000  0 0
//192.168.0.5/media                       /mnt/media     cifs    rw,relatime,cache=strict,username=aabor,password=<pwd>,domain=WORKGROUP,gid=1000,uid=1000  0 0
```

The host is Centos Stream 8, so I also have to adjust SELinux permissions (on the host):

```
sudo setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro=1 samba_export_all_rw=1
getsebool -a | grep samba_export
sudo semanage fcontext -at samba_share_t "/mnt/shared_home(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon /mnt/shared_home
sudo semanage fcontext -at samba_share_t "/mnt/media(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon /mnt/media
```

Both shares are available on the guest, I can browse and change the files.

But when I change any system settings it can't be saved into user profile. Ubuntu does not saves into current user profile the power management, fonts and any other settings.
For example, when I try to set `nemo` as default file manager I get errors:

`(nemo:4537): dconf-WARNING **: 13:17:15.032: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Failed to rename file “/home/aabor/.config/dconf/user.0WKTV1” to “/home/aabor/.config/dconf/user”: g_rename() failed: Permission denied`

What is appropriate way to set up samba share on the host if I intend to use it as user's home directory on several guest machines?

Comment: Are the Ubuntu guests running simultaneously? Or are you running them one at a time?

Comment: I run them one at a time.